# Can I set a background-color to margins and padding?

Tags: css

I want to color the margins and padding of a `<div>` so that I can use it educationally to represent the box-model in CSS.  How can I set a color for those elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to set the `background-color`s of the padding and margin attributes.  They are meant to be transparent, or invisible, and used solely for positioning purposes.

However, I have heard this question many times, and I completely understand wanting to show the padding and margins for purely educational purposes.  Therefore, I have created a simple little "hack" to represent the box-model, using CSS's `:before` and `:after` psuedo-elements.

You can't color padding, or margins, but let me suggest a little hack to make it look like you can (without JavaScript!):

## simulated box-model:

```css
#box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
#box:before {
  background: red;
  content: 'border';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: -30px;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: -30px;
  z-index: -1;
}
#box:after {
  background: gray;
  content: 'margin';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: -50px;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">#box</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

The property that you are looking for is background-clip

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 30px solid transparent;
    background-color: blue;
}
.test1 {background-clip: content-box;}
.test2 {background-clip: padding-box;}
.test3 {background-clip: border-box;}
```

```html
<div class="test1"></div>
<div class="test2"></div>
<div class="test3"></div>
```

And another solution, combining both in a single div

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 30px solid transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, yellow, yellow), 
                      linear-gradient(0deg, green, green), 
                      linear-gradient(0deg, blue, blue);
    background-clip: content-box, padding-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```